# Input selected row and ignore duplicate row

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2008, duplicates

I have a problem that I need to insert a selected row from the table to another table based on `last_update` data or `last_transaction_product`. `last_update` is the data updated from the table, and `last_transaction_product` is the latest transaction from my shop, and then my row has duplicate data but has a different `last_update` column here, this duplicate data must not be inserted to my destination table here, because of the data has already inserted on destination table.

For example, I have 3 tables here.

1. Source Table AS `Table_Source`
2. Destination Table AS `Table_Destination`
3. Log Table AS `Table_Log`

My problem is, my Source Table and Destination Table didn't have any `PK` that can be used for the identity of the Row table.

1. So here are my `Table_Source`

| product_name | shop_name | last_transaction_product | last_update |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Clock | Benefical | 2020-04-15 | 2020-06-01 |
| Monitor | Hinezo Computer | 2020-01-17 | 2020-06-01 |
| Notebook | LA Shop | 2020-03-25 | 2020-06-01 |

2. I have a query that inserts it to `Table_Destination` based on `> @last_transaction_product` or `> @last_update`, here are my `Table_Destination` after inserted from `Table_Source`, and I'm inserted it at 2020-06-02

| product_name | shop_name | last_transaction_product | last_update |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Clock | Benefical | 2020-04-15 | 2020-06-01 |
| Monitor | Hinezo Computer | 2020-01-17 | 2020-06-01 |
| Notebook | LA Shop | 2020-03-25 | 2020-06-01 |

3. After it inserted into my `Table_Destination`, it will save the record from the latest activity table to `Table_Log`, so here my `Table_Log` after inserted.

| table_name | last_transaction_product | last_update | last_run |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Table_Source | 2020-04-15 | 2020-06-01 | 2020-06-02 |

4. And the next time, there was new data inserted at `Table_Source`

| product_name | shop_name | last_transaction_product | last_update |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Clock | Benefical | 2020-04-15 | 2020-06-01 |
| Monitor | Hinezo Computer | 2020-01-17 | 2020-06-01 |
| Notebook | LA Shop | 2020-03-25 | 2020-06-01 |
| Poster | Maniac Shop | 2020-04-27 | 2020-06-03 |
| Clock | Benefical | 2020-04-15 | 2020-06-03 |

5. As you can see from the newest table of `Table_Source` there was a duplicated data `('Clock', 'Benefical', '2020-04-15', '2020-06-03')` that has a different last_update. In my case, I want to excluded this duplicated data to insert into my `Table_Destination`, so it will only insert the `('Poster', 'Maniac Shop', '2020-04-27', '2020-06-03')`, and of course I used latest `last_transaction_product` and `last_update` from `Table_Log` as my parameter to inserting into `Table_Destination` . So my `Table_Destination` and my `Table_Log` will be like this.

| product_name | shop_name | last_transaction_product | last_update |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Clock | Benefical | 2020-04-15 | 2020-06-01 |
| Monitor | Hinezo Computer | 2020-01-17 | 2020-06-01 |
| Notebook | LA Shop | 2020-03-25 | 2020-06-01 |
| Poster | Maniac Shop | 2020-04-27 | 2020-06-03 |

| table_name | last_transaction_product | last_update | last_run |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Table_Source | 2020-04-15 | 2020-06-01 | 2020-06-02 |
| Table_Source | 2020-04-27 | 2020-06-03 | 2020-06-04 |

So here are my T-SQL now

```
BEGIN
    -- INSERT DESTINATION DATA --
    SET Table_Destination ON;
    INSERT INTO 
        Table_Destination
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        Table_Source
    WHERE 
        last_transaction_product > (SELECT MAX(last_transaction_product) FROM Table_Log WHERE table_name = 'Table_Source')
        OR
        last_update > (SELECT MAX(last_update) FROM Table_Log WHERE table_name = 'Table_Source')

    SET Table_Destination OFF;

    -- INSERT LOG UPDATE --
    INSERT INTO Table_Log(table_name, last_transaction_product, last_update, last_run)
    VALUES('Table_Source', (SELECT MAX(last_transaction_product) FROM Table_Source WHERE table_name = 'Table_Source'), (SELECT MAX(last_update) FROM Table_Source WHERE table_name = 'Table_Source'),  @Date)
END;
```

**Note:**

- This is the flow for inserting of my Data [Data Inserting Flow](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1YkvmuTHzNOO5trBsQSO6nF0Vitqcyq15VIOVuk5nGFI/edit?usp=sharing)
- I don't want this logic using the `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` query, because in my case I have 10 million rows from the `Table_Source` and `Table_Destination`. Because it will make my database work too hard.

Comment: Hello I just want add a minor remarks: you should to use ```SELECT ts.*``` instead ```SELECT *```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `NOT EXISTS`, it is your best option because of the semi-join.

If you have problems with millions rows you should check your indexes.
`Table_Destination` hahas no duplicates for `product_name` so indexing it (in both tables) is a good start and a join on it should not be terrific.

Also, there is something strange in your `WHERE` clause..

I will try this

**EDIT**

Added a condition in `NOT EXISTS` to get a product inserted in destination once per shop instead of only once.

Added also protection for 1st run when `Table_Log` is empty.

```
SET Table_Destination ON;

INSERT INTO 
    Table_Destination
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    Table_Source ts,
    (
        SELECT 
            MAX(last_transaction_product) max_last_transaction_product, 
            MAX(last_update) max_last_update 
        FROM Table_Log 
        WHERE table_name = 'Table_Source'
    ) agg
WHERE 
    (
        last_transaction_product > ISNULL(max_last_transaction_product, 0)
        OR 
        last_update > ISNULL(max_last_update, 0)
    )
    AND
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL 
        FROM Table_Destination td
        WHERE td.product_name = ts.product_name
        /* REMOVE BELOW LINE IF YOU NEED PRODUCTS IN DEST ONLY ONCE
        KEEP THE LINE IF YOU WANT PRODUCT REPEATED ONCE FOR EACH SHOP */
        AND td.shop_name = ts.shop_name 
    )

SET Table_Destination OFF;
```

Comment: Oh, sorry I've update my T-SQL now, but now my question, how to check my indexes ? and I need to join both table and then insert it to `Table_Destination`?

Comment: Okay, I will try your suggest

Comment: I have tried the query that you gift. But, when I add the `Table_Source` with a same product_name and a different shop_name, it only Insert the `Printer` row only. For example There are 3 new row `('Clock', 'Benefical', '2020-04-15', '2020-06-05')`, `('Clock', 'WatchId', '2020-04-02', '2020-06-05')`, `('Printer', 'Hinezo Computer', '2020-04-20', '2020-06-05')`. From this 3 row, it only insert the `('Printer', 'Hinezo Computer', '2020-04-20', '2020-06-05')`. But, I really appreciate for your answer. Thank you

Comment: but isn't what you asked to **NOT** to insert products already present in `Table_Destination`?

Comment: I'm sorry for my late update. Thank you very much for your update. It solved now.